# Mac Terminal support for multiple fonts

Tags: mac, terminal, font, emacs

I was trying to get emacs minimap to work on the terminal - http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MiniMap

However, the font is the same size as the rest of the screen, which makes it pretty useless. It seems to be the same in iTerm.

[image]

The standalone Emacs.app works, but I'd rather not use it.

[image]

Is there a mac terminal which supports multiple fonts?

Comment: What about using an X11 terminal, running under [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'll be possible - terminal-based applications (as those running in terminal emulators like Terminal.app, iTerm.app, etc are) don't support multiple concurrent fonts. This is because a terminal application is written to run on a traditional dumb terminal which wouldn't have the concept of multiple fonts. Within a terminal emulator, all text is displayed in the same font and this is why the sidebar doesn't look as it should.

The only solution is to use a version of Emacs running under either Cocoa/Carbon (eg, Emacs.app or Aquamacs) or X11.