# How to activate the second font in MacOS Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, font

I want to activate 2 fonts at the same time in macOS terminal: FiraCode(a Coding Font) and AwesomeFont(a Symbol Font).

I have installed them. However, I can only choose one of them: When I choose FiraCode in Preferences, the AwesomeFont is unactivated.

In my Linux OS, the AwesomeFont is always activated in Terminal. if I have installed it. How to activate the second font in macOS Terminal?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83159/mac-terminal-support-for-multiple-fonts